# How can I edit a pre existing component in Altium design?

Tags: pcb, altium

There are some simple component in Altium Desing like LED or Diod or Resistors but How can we edit or modify them because its schematic and pins are good , I want to add a 3D object or some text or lines to it , but I don't know how?

It is easy for component file which could be found in internet because they are a simple file which adds to your project but the altium component are part of a bigger library like miscellaneous devices.

PS : By modifying, I don't mean to double clicking on theme and change some properties , I mean editing their schematics and PCB layout.

Comment: Simply open the library (from FIle -> Open) and you can edit the part, add 3D, annotate with text - whatever you need or want to do is available.

Answer (score 1):

If you already have the .schlib or .pcblib. You simply open it, then open the Schematic/PCB Library panel in the bottom right. Then you can double click on any part and start editing with the toolbar at the top and properties.

If you do not have the libraries created, you can easily make them by, when in you schematic or PCB design, clicking design -> Make PCB/Schematic Library on the top toolbar.

Hope this helps.